# SSH connection frozen on "enter password" after "watch mysqladmin"

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line, ssh, terminal

The server we're using is a Linode running Debian 7. I'm using Terminal on OS X to connect via SSH.

While connected to the box via SSH, I typed "watch mysqladmin -u root -p password" and it prompted me with "Enter password:". And it's stuck there.

Typing a password and pressing enter does nothing. Control-C didn't work. The console is completely unresponsive.

Any ideas on how I can exit this prompt? I'm relatively new to the command line so the help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And if `Ctrl+D` doesn't work, I'd login in another terminal and run `kill \`pidof watch\`` (assuming I'm not allowed / able to kill the process of another user). FWIW: no space after the `-p` works.

Answer (score 2):

If you try running mysqladmin directly, using

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

Then you'll see that half the problem is that the password isn't getting passed to mysqladmin. Try removing the space:

```
mysqladmin -u root -ppassword
```

The watch command is not intended for running interactive code - hence it doesn't read what you type at the prompt - and it isolates the command from the terminal.

I can't imagine a good reason for runnning mysqladmin via watch - but doing it as you do, anyone with an account on the box will be able to see the root mysql password - it would be much safer to use a [user options file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) to set the password.

As for terminating the existing process, if a SIGINT (ctrl+c) doesn't work, you could try a SIGQUIT (ctrl+<kbd>\</kbd>) and if that doesn't work then try `killproc watch` as Wrikken suggests (ctrl+d is unlikely to work if the SIGs on't work)